# Route all traffic from one interface to default gateway with different IP

Tags: linux, routing, iptables

The situation:

eth0 - Default network with internet access
IP: 192.168.2.1
Defatult Gateway: 192.168.2.254

eth0:1 192.168.2.2
Virtual NIC, same thing as eth0 but different IP. Same cable
This ip has a different internet access

eth1: 192.168.0.1

eth2: 192.168.1.1

All traffic from eth1 and eth2 are routed to 192.168.2.254 using 192.168.2.1

I need to route all traffic coming from eth2 to 192.168.2.254 but using the secondary ip 192.168.2.2

I tried a lot of different configurations but no success.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is called source policy routing. Instructions for configuring source policy routing can be found [here in the Linux Advanced Routing & Traffic Control HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.rpdb.simple.html).

The crux of it is that you want to add a new routing table to your system with a name like INET2 (these commands must be run as root):

```
echo 200 INET2 >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

Then you want to add a source rule to the main IP routing table (I'm guessing this is a /24 network):

```
ip rule add from 192.168.1.0/24 table INET2
```

Next you need to assign a default route for the INET2 table (you did not mention the default gateway for your second connection so I'm guessing here):

```
ip route add default via 192.168.2.253 dev eth0:1 table INET2
```

Lastly, you need to flush the route cache on the system:

```
ip route flush cache
```

Rules created this way are ephemeral and will disappear when the system is restarted (though the INET2 table will persist) so you'll need to put the rules into a startup script for the network interface. Exactly how to do this depends on your particular distribution of Linux and is really another question.

Comment: It worked! It didn't worked with a virtual interface on Debian, but I installed a spare NIC and it worked. Thank you.